# Flex / Air sqlite async issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I am writing an app that parses a csv file to an array and then insert the array into a sqlite database. I am having issues with Async connection to the sqlite database, I get a 3106 error...... I think the problem is that it executes the next statement before the previous is finished but I can't find a way to deal with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function addData(categories:Array):void{
                status = "Adding data to table";
                var insrtStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                    insrtStmt.sqlConnection = conn;


                        for(var i:int=categories.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                            insrtStmt.text = "";
                            insrtStmt.text += "INSERT INTO masterlist ";
                            insrtStmt.text += "(mainid, transactionDate, tradeId, ccyPair, account, buySell, customer, date,"; 
                            insrtStmt.text += " additionalid, dealType, traderName, genericType, owner) ";
                            insrtStmt.text += "VALUES(@mainid, @transactionDate, @tradeId, @ccyPair, @account, @buySell, @customer, @date,";
                            insrtStmt.text += " @additionalid, @dealType, @traderName, @genericType, @owner);";
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@mainid"] = categories[i].mainid;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@transactionDate"] = categories[i].transactionDate;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@tradeId"] = categories[i].tradeId;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@ccyPair"] = categories[i].ccyPair;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@account"] = categories[i].account;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@buySell"] = categories[i].buySell;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@customer"] = categories[i].customer;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@date"] = categories[i].date;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@additionalid"] = categories[i].additionalid;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@dealType"] = categories[i].dealType;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@traderName"] = categories[i].traderName;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@genericType"] = categories[i].genericType;
                            insrtStmt.parameters["@owner"] = categories[i].owner;
                            insrtStmt.execute();
                            }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you think the problem is that it is still executing, just add an event listener to the statement for it's "result" event, and then fire off the next statements.

```
public function addDataSet( categories : Array ) : void {
    _categories = categories;
    _loopcounter = categories.length;
    _insrtStmt : SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    _insrtStmt.addEventListener( "result", addData );
    addData();
}

public function addData(event : Event = null) : void {
    _loopcounter--;
    // Set up rest of statement
    _insrtStmt.execute();
}
```

Comment: You should never use loops like that to wait for an event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a synchronous connection instead of an async one?  If needed you can open multiple connections to the same db and use the appropriate connection.

Answer (score 0):

For executing multiple commands at once - use transactions.

Simple example from http://www.zedia.net/2009/air-sqlite-optimization-tricks/

```
_updateStmt.sqlConnection = _conn;
_updateStmt.text = "UPDATE main.myTable SET statusF=@STATUS  WHERE keyId=@ID";

_conn.begin();//_conn is a SQLConnection, I didn't take the time to write the code for it, but this is where the magic happens

for (var i:uint = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++){
  _updateStmt.parameters["@STATUS"] = currentArray[i].status;
  _updateStmt.parameters["@ID"] = currentArray[i].id;
  _updateStmt.execute();
}

_conn.commit();
```

Also have a look at the adobe flex livedocs chapter 'Improving database performance'

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create a new SQLStatement for each query, that way you don't need to wait and you can fire the inserts off as fast as the client machine can process them.

```
public function addData(categories:Array):void {
    status = "Adding data to table";
    var insrtStmt:SQLStatement;

    for(var i:int=categories.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        insrtStmt = new SQLStatement();
        insrtStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
        insrtStmt.text = "";
        insrtStmt.text += "INSERT INTO masterlist ";
        insrtStmt.text += "(mainid, transactionDate, tradeId, ccyPair, account, buySell, customer, date,"; 
        insrtStmt.text += " additionalid, dealType, traderName, genericType, owner) ";
        insrtStmt.text += "VALUES(@mainid, @transactionDate, @tradeId, @ccyPair, @account, @buySell, @customer, @date,";
        insrtStmt.text += " @additionalid, @dealType, @traderName, @genericType, @owner);";
        insrtStmt.parameters["@mainid"] = categories[i].mainid;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@transactionDate"] = categories[i].transactionDate;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@tradeId"] = categories[i].tradeId;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@ccyPair"] = categories[i].ccyPair;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@account"] = categories[i].account;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@buySell"] = categories[i].buySell;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@customer"] = categories[i].customer;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@date"] = categories[i].date;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@additionalid"] = categories[i].additionalid;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@dealType"] = categories[i].dealType;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@traderName"] = categories[i].traderName;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@genericType"] = categories[i].genericType;
        insrtStmt.parameters["@owner"] = categories[i].owner;
        insrtStmt.execute();
    }
}
```